# Automatically launching and running C# VSTO Add-In application

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I have a C# VSTO Outlook Add-In application which needs to be run 9:30 am on the weekdays. I am asked to make it run automatically using a timer. But even on timer we need to keep the application running but here I want to make the program run on its own at that time keeping the application closed.

I tried creating an exe file and tried running it using Task Scheduler but it just runs the setup but doesn't actually run the Add-In startup code. How can I do this? Is there a way to write code within the same ThisAddIn class which can launch the Add-In code at my specific time without Task Scheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by restructuring your solution:

- Add a console app to your solution (this will be the tool that you call from your scheduled task)
- Add a new class library project to your solution and place all code that is common to your add-in and the command line tool in this class library
- Add a reference to the class library project to both the command line tool and your VSTO add-in.